# Coffeescript Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

Any idea why the `@layout = @getLayoutView()` line is throwing a `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` error? I can't seem to figure it out. As always any help is very much appreciated!

list_controller.js.coffee:

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    List.Controller =

      listUsers: ->
        users = App.request "user:entities"
        @layout = @getLayoutView()
        App.mainRegion.show @layout

      getLayoutView: ->
        new List.Layout
```

list_view.js.coffee:

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Layout = new Marionette.LayoutView
    template: "users/list/templates/list_layout"
```

**EDIT** Adding Routing Logic

user_app.js.coffee:

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp", (UsersApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class UsersApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
        appRoutes:
            "users": "listUsers"

    API =
        listUsers: ->
            UsersApp.List.Controller.listUsers()

    App.addInitializer ->
        new UsersApp.Router
            controller: API
```

app.js.coffee:

```
@Demo = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  App.rootRoute = "users"

  App.addRegions
    headerRegion: "#header-region"
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
    footerRegion: "#footer-region"

  App.addInitializer ->
    App.module("HeaderApp").start()
    App.module("FooterApp").start()

  App.on "start", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start()
      @navigate(@rootRoute, trigger: true) if @getCurrentRoute() is ""

  App
```

Comment: What calls `listUsers` and why do you expect `@` to be anything in particular when it that function is called?

Comment: Sure - I added my code above. Probably worth noting I tried removing the this or @ from layout, but it does the same thing. I'm actually following Brian Mann's tutorial at backbonerails.com which states it is needed later in the controller.

Comment: To your question though - 'listUsers' is called when the user navigates to the localhost:3000/users url (or they are routed there after going to the localhost:3000 url as well via the last function in app.js.coffee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you supposed to extend List.Layout from 'Marionette.LayoutView', but the code snippet here creating a instance of 'Marionette.LayoutView'. The code

```
List.Layout = new Marionette.LayoutView
    template: "users/list/templates/list_layout"
```

should have been

```
class List.Layout extends  Marionette.LayoutView
   template: "users/list/templates/list_layout"
```